# How to find two default submit buttons when i press the Enter key in asp.net using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have two default submit buttons in a single web page; one is in the main form, and another one button is inside a div control. This div control will be popup at login button click event, so when I popup this div. This div has a submit button and when I press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, this button needs to submit. If this div is closed, I press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key on the main form submit button to submit the values. How can I find the two submit buttons on the <kbd>enter</kbd> key press even using jQuery? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When the popup shows up, set the focus to the submit button of the popup div:

```
$('div.popupclass').find('button[type="submit"]').focus();
```

And, when the popup is closed, switch the focus back to the main form:

```
$('body').find('button[type="submit"]').focus();
```

if you are using jQuery-UI's dialog, then put those lines in the open: and close: calls.

Comment: When the popup div open i set the focus to a textbox (username) .. and after close the popup i have set the focus to another textbox control in tab control..  The Submit button in login popup works default when i press enter key.. but not main form's submit button..

Comment: Are trying to make it so that whenever the enter key is pressed on the main body, the main form to be submitted?

Comment: Actually.. the login popup submit button execute atleast one time.. when i press enter key.. i have tried to find the Enter key and trigger the each button as i required.. but even the popup submit button will be called two times.. if i try to submit form button.. the login button also get submitted..

Comment: Based on your description so far, having trouble understanding what behaviors of the buttons you would like to implement. Please try to be more clear on the behaviors of the buttons and keys.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.. you were right, i tried this with sample application and what i come to know is, if we place a two button in a form and when we get focus on any input controls inside the form, by default the first button got focus.. so when we press enter key.. the first button submitted by default.. so i am here changed the focus on buttons based on simple if else condition and move focus and trigger click event using jquery.. so here i solved my issue.. Thank u... thank u so much for your responses..

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out!